# use single variable to find table row where the tables column is an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leg 
WHERE trailers = '$VehicleID')
```

`$VehicleID` is a single variable.

`trailers` is the column that is an array made up of 1 or more variables

At the moment it just returns the table rows that have only the 1 `$VehicleID` variable in the trailers column.

How do I make trailers return all rows that has `$VehicleID` variable contained in the array?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. It's awful and is being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices. Always be absolutely **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the advise tadman I plan on checking it out soon. The site is not a concern for me at the moment I am just teaching myself how to use aspects of PHP. I do use the 'mysql_real_escape_string ' if thats what you mean.

Comment: I understand you're just learning and that's why you're wasting your time and learning some truly terrible habits by using `mysql_query`. PDO makes it significantly easier to write correct query code, named placeholders is a huge deal. If you're serious about learning PHP, modern development practices encourage the use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) as a solid foundation for building applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IN` clause and `implode` function.

```
$VehicleID = array(1, 4, 5, 6);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leg 
WHERE trailers IN (" . implode(',', $VehicleID) . ")");
```

You need to check more states:
1) there is a single number: `trailers = $VehicleID`
2) the number is at the beginning in the field: `trailers LIKE '$VehicleID,%'`
3) the number is at the end in the field: `trailers LIKE '%,$VehicleID'`
4) the number is in the middle in the field: `trailers LIKE '%,$VehicleID,%'`

Now you need to use all option using `OR` clause (please, don't forget to SQL injection):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM leg 
WHERE trailers =     $VehicleID    OR
      trailers LIKE '$VehicleID,%' OR
      trailers LIKE '%,$VehicleID' OR
      trailers LIKE '%,$VehicleID,%'
```

Correct DB schema:
Create new table, eg. `trailers` with 2 cols: `trailer_id`, `vehicle_id`

In this case, when you have in `$VehicleID` for values, there will be 4 rows in this new table.

Comment: hey panther thanks for getting back to me so quickly. I have seen your response many times when researching the problem it seems the only one. However $VehicleID is NOT an array as I said, it is a single variable such as 1 or 4 etc but never 1,4,5,6 etc.  So maybe you can help me again. How can I match it to the trailers column, the single variable $VehicleID, where it is contained singularly or amongst an array of variables? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @DanWalsh: in `trailers` column is value like `1,2,5,6`?

Comment: @DanWalsh: please restructure your database. This is bad DB layout. In `WHERE` clause you need in your situation more options: See updated answer. But know that this is the first problem, other will be there soon.

Comment: Thanks it works a treat. I'm not sure how I would change the layout of the DB. I saw this method before and appreciate that it looks cumbersome. I just thought there would be a more simpler method that experts such as yourself may shed some light on. thanks again.